# Vuejs, how to pass props to a Component rendered by Router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue-props

I new in Vuejs, so apologize this is a newbie question.

I have added a router to my App and I would like to render data from my main App into my Components templates but it is not working.

This is what I have:

```
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const Text = { props: ['text'], template: '<div>This is the text: {{text}} </div>' }

const routes = [
  { path: '*', component: Text, props: true }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: routes
})

new Vue({
  router: router,
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    text: "Hello there!"
  }
})
```

I was expected the `text` prop to be linked to my `App.data.text` but it is not happening.

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/psqztn93

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const Text = {
  props: ["text"],
  template: "<div>This is the text: {{text}} </div>"
};

const routes = [{ path: "*", component: Text }];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: routes
});

new Vue({
  router: router,
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    text: "Hello there!"
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-router@3.1.3/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <router-view :text="text"></router-view>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to forward the props via [router-view](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view) (which here passes  `text` to the rendered component  `Text`)

```
<router-view :text="text"></router-view>
```